# Want my content to be responsive with bootstrap, but it doesnt "work"

Tags: html, css

I have a page where the layout starts with a simple text and under it there is another text in a box i made myself in just css. On the right of that i have a slideshow i took from a site that lines up good with the text in the box. That is my layout, and when using bootstrap it doesnt really "work". I want the content to move down when having lower resolutions, and it really doesnt work that well. I tried using the col-xs-6 and other examples but it didnt really work. Im actually not sure if this is making any sense, but what i want is to make my all content be responsive and react to the size of the current pagesize and adapt in the form of going just vertically down or something like that.

Here is my code, i have alot of "fillercode in the text so sry for the big mess :/"

```
<div class="TimmageH1">Serien utspelar sig på den fiktiva kontinenten Västeros, ofta kallad "De sju kungarikena". Eddard "Ned" Stark (Sean Bean), lord av Vinterfell, bekymras av rykten från muren i norr då han får besked om att Jon Arryn, hans mentor och kungens hand, dött av feber och att kung Robert Baratheon (Mark Addy) är på väg till Winterfell. Ned blir tillfrågad om att ersätta Arryn som kungens hand och reser till Kungshamn för att assistera kungen. Familjen Stark delas då upp genom att Ned och döttrarna Arya och Sansa åker till Kungshamn. Kvar i Vinterhed är Catelyn och hennes söner. Jon Snow, Neds oäkting som är illa omtyckt av Catelyn, beger sig till muren i norr för att bli en edsvuren man i Nattväktarna, den traditionstyngda vaktstyrka som försvarar muren som separerar den avlägsna norden. På andra sidan havet på kontinenten Essos smider exilprinsen Viserys Targaryen (Harry Lloyd) planer för att återerövra De sju kungarikena. Han gifter bort sin yngre syster Daenerys till stamkungen Khal Drogo. Daenerys blir senare en av huvudkaraktärerna då hon också har planer på att sitta på järntronen. Andra pretendenter är Roberts yngre bröder Stannis och Renly, som ser sig som Roberts legitima arvtagare. I norr gör Neds äldste son Robb anspråk på att vara "kungen i Norr" och på Järnöarna utropar sig lord Balon till kung av Järnöarna.</div>

<div class="GreyBG"><div class="Patchnotes"><h2>Patch Notes (Elr slideshow/liknande)</h2></div><div class="TimmageH2">Serien utspelar sig på den fiktiva kontinenten Västeros, ofta kallad "De sju kungarikena". Eddard "Ned" Stark (Sean Bean), lord av Vinterfell, bekymras av rykten från muren i norr då han får besked om att Jon Arryn, hans mentor och kungens hand, dött av feber och att kung Robert Baratheon (Mark Addy) är på väg till Winterfell. Ned blir tillfrågad om att ersätta Arryn som kungens hand och reser till Kungshamn för att assistera kungen. Familjen Stark delas då upp genom att Ned och döttrarna Arya och Sansa åker till Kungshamn. Kvar i Vinterhed är Catelyn och hennes söner. Jon Snow, Neds oäkting som är illa omtyckt av Catelyn, beger sig till muren i norr för att bli en edsvuren man i Nattväktarna, den traditionstyngda vaktstyrka som försvarar muren som separerar den avlägsna norden. På andra sidan havet på kontinenten Essos smider exilprinsen Viserys Targaryen (Harry Lloyd) planer för att återerövra De sju kungarikena. Han gifter bort sin yngre syster Daenerys till stamkungen Khal Drogo. Daenerys blir senare en av huvudkaraktärerna då hon också har planer på att sitta på järntronen. Andra pretendenter är Roberts yngre bröder Stannis och Renly, som ser sig som Roberts legitima arvtagare. I norr gör Neds äldste son Robb anspråk på att vara "kungen i Norr" och på Järnöarna utropar sig lord Balon till kung av Järnöarna.</div></div> 

<!-- Här börjar script länkning till bootstrap, modal och främst slideshowen. -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<!-- Här slutar script länkning till bootstrap, modal och främst slideshowen. -->

  <div class="SlideshowPosition">
<!-- use jssor.slider.debug.js instead for debug -->
```

Comment: Dont mind the foreign language in the end, it went wrong at  the end D:

Comment: Edit your post to remove the foreign language.

Comment: @GMchris, the question is in english. The foreign language is part of the content of the page, and does not affect the ability to understand the problem of this question. The foreign language should stay.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap makes use of a grid system to make content responsive. This means you should always place your content in a row and within the row in columns. When the content becomes to big for the screen size to be placed next to each other, it will be placed under each other.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Left-side of the page</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Right-side of the page</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want the content only stacked on very small devices you can use xs, if you want it stacked on anything under 'medium' screen size you use md, etc.

I also advise you to read up on it here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thank you for that answer, ill be sure to try that out! I'll notify you if something goes wrong. Btw, can you upload pictures or gifs on this post? I think it would be easier to show how it looks or something.

Comment: If you go to the bootstrap website and check out the grid, you can just make your browser screen bigger and smaller and see what happens.